# There was no endpoint listening at https://... that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf

I'm using a 3rd party web service, i can view and run it no problem from the browser

[image]

I've added the Service References to visual studio and specified the namespage:

[image]

As it's a web app so i've copied the relevant bits from app.config to web.config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MembersSoap">
          <security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/> 
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
         </binding>
        <binding name="BookingsSoap">
          <security mode="Transport"> 
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/> 
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" algorithmSuite="Default" />
         </security>
         </binding> 

      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://server/directory/Members.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MembersSoap" contract="MWSMembers.MembersSoap" name="MembersSoap" />
      <endpoint address="https://server/directory/Bookings.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BookingsSoap" contract="MWSBookings.BookingsSoap" name="BookingsSoap" />

   </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Here's my method using the MWSBookings web service:

```
private string GetBookings()
{
    using (MWSBookings.BookingsSoapClient client = new MWSBookings.BookingsSoapClient())
    {
        try
        {

            var bookings = client.ListBookableActivitiesClassesCourses(GetMemberAuthHeader2(), 0123456, "5", false);
            return bookings.ToString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message.ToString();
        }
    }


}
```

When i build my solution and view the browser page i get the following error:

**There was no endpoint listening at https://server/directory/Bookings.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.**

I have searched through all the other posts on Stack Overflow and none of the solutions have helped my situation.  I've ensured the HTTP Activation Feature is installed, I've tried running the AppPool from appPoolIdentity to NetworkService and that didn't help.  Also tried including maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength in web.config and increasing limits but no difference.

I'd be grateful if anyone can offer any advise.

thanks
Scott

**UPDATE**
Here's the full exception message:

```
        System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at https://server/directory/Bookings.asmx 
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. 

See InnerException, if present, for more details. --->

System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the 
connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or 
established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 
MYIP:443 at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, 
SocketAddress socketAddress) at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket 
s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, 
IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) --- End of inner exception 
stack trace --- at 
    System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) at 
System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() at 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream(
) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack trace: at 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStream(
) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.Send(TimeSpan timeout) at 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChan
nelRequest.SendRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, 
TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String 
action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, 
Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at 
    System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMes
sage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) 
Exception rethrown at [0]: at 
    System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage 
reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at 
    System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& 
msgData, Int32 type) at 
    MySolution.MWSBookings.BookingsSoap.ListBookableActivitiesClassesCourses(List
BookableActivitiesClassesCoursesRequest request) at 
    MySolution.MWSBookings.BookingsSoapClient.MySolution.MWSBookings.BookingsSoap
.ListBookableActivitiesClassesCourses(ListBookableActivitiesClassesCoursesReq
uest request) in D:\website\branches\csharp\Service References\MWSBookings
\Reference.cs:line 4464 at MySolution.MWSBookings.BookingsSoapClient.ListBookableActivitiesClassesCourses(AuthHeader AuthHeader, Int32 memberId, String siteId, Boolean webBookableOnly) in D:\website\branches\csharp\Service References\MWSBookings\Reference.cs:line 4473 at MySolution.ActivityFinder.GetBookings() in D:\website\branches\csharp\Service References\Classes\MyClass.cs:line 97
```

Comment: 1, did you have to install any auth cert to connect to the site (when you bring-up a web browser, does it ask you to choose a cert)?  2. Is there any authentication (login/Pw)?  3. In your Catch block, you should change it: if there is an InnerException, return that message, else, return the Exception message.

Comment: Maybe firewall is blocking your app? Make sure you run it under administrative privileges

Comment: @tgolisch hi, i think i may be having problems because of a proxy server, what's the correct settings I should use in web.config if my traffic requires to go through a proxy server?  i've tried <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="Windows" realm=""/> with no luck

Comment: @komsky hi Komsky, i don't think  it's a firewall issue, i've posted some further exception message above and it suggests it's a proxy issue.  Any idea how i add proxy credentials to allow the app to pass through?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with a  proxy server, i've added the following lines before i call my webservice and the error message has now gone.

```
var proxy = new WebProxy("myproxy:8080", true);

proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = proxy;
```